# Is heavy (slf4j logger) method overloading an anti-pattern?

Tags: overloading, anti-patterns

slf4j is heavily overloading methods:

```
Method Summary
 void   debug(Marker marker, String msg) 
          Log a message with the specific Marker at the DEBUG level.
 void   debug(Marker marker, String format, Object... arguments) 
          This method is similar to debug(String, Object...)
 void   debug(Marker marker, String format, Object arg) 
          This method is similar to debug(String, Object) method except that the marker data is also taken into consideration.
 void   debug(Marker marker, String format, Object arg1, Object arg2) 
          This method is similar to debug(String, Object, Object) method except that the marker data is also taken into consideration.
 void   debug(Marker marker, String msg, Throwable t) 
          This method is similar to debug(String, Throwable) method except that the marker data is also taken into consideration.
 void   debug(String msg)
```

is this an **antipattern** as **[elegant code](http://elegantcode.com/2010/06/20/prefer-additional-methods-over-additional-overloads/)**  specifies?

Comment: It's best not to think too hard about Java. There are no good choices.

Comment: What does this question have to do with Scala or functional programming?

Comment: @ChrisMartin in `fp` perhaps i could first call a function with argument `marker` and get back a function which I could further call with `msg` thus maybe it could save me from the overloading (so at least i thought `fp` could help with overloading)

Comment: In Java I think you're better off with the builder pattern. e.g. you could design this logging API with a single method `void log(Message)` where `Message` has builder methods and the usage looks something like `logger.log(debug().marker(a).message(b).args(c, d))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each pattern can become antipattern if it is used incorrectly. Some anti patterns can become good if their usage is reasonable.

In case of slf4j and most other logging APIs this overloading seems reasonable. Logging API should be simple yet powerful enough for user and is not being changed frequently. This is the reason that most logging APIs I know are built as Facade to lower level functionality.

Think about logging API like

```
public void log(Level level, Formatter formatter, LogMessage msg);
```

Every time when you want to print message like "User John has logged in successfully" you have to create object of formatter and `LogMessage` and refer to `Level.INFO`. Is it simpler to call method like

```
public void info(String message, Object ... args);
```

that will call lower level method `log()` with all needed parameters.

This is what `slf4j` does for you. So it has method for each log level and for each useful scenario:

- with and without marker
- with and without throwable
- with simple message and with format + arguments

IMHO for me sounds reasonable.